How to form a SELECT query in Couchbase for objects based on a field in an array
I have a couchbase with documents (in a bucket called myBucket) each of whose structure is like so:
{
  "id": 1234
  "name": "Smith",
  "properties": [
    {
      "address": 12,
      "color": red
    },
    {
      "address": 13,
      "color": blue
    },
    {
      "address": 9,
      "color": red
    }
  ]
}

As an example, I could make a call to retrieve a list of all names where the id field is 1234 like so:
SELECT name FROM myBucket WHERE id = '1234'

and this would return the array ["Smith"]
What query should I write in order to return a list of all the addresses where the id field is 1234 and the color member of the properties field is red?
So in this case I would like to return the array [12,9].
I have tried this:
SELECT properties.address FROM myBucket WHERE id = '1234'

But this returns an array of 2 elements but each is an empty object.

I solved this with: SELECT a.address FROM myBucket AS o UNNEST o.properties AS a WHERE  a.color= 'red'

In your case, your answer is a good approach, since you want to actually select the address:
SELECT a.address
FROM myBucket AS o
UNNEST o.properties AS a
WHERE a.color = 'red'

But just for the record, if you wanted to select the whole document, you could use ANY...SATISFIES...END syntax, like so:
SELECT m.* from myBucket._default._default m
WHERE ANY p IN m.properties SATISFIES p.color == "red" END

